# curl ftp: Cannot connect on aws instance

Tags: networking, ftp, amazon-ec2, curl

When I try to download a file via curl/ftp while on an AWS box, it just hangs:

```
$ curl -vvvvv -4 --ftp-pasv ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt
*   Trying 205.167.25.101:21...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

Here is a successful call from my laptop:
Here is the successful call from my laptop:

```
$ curl -vvvvv -4 --ftp-pasv ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt > /dev/null
*   Trying 205.167.25.101:21...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov (205.167.25.101) port 21 (#0)
< 220 205.167.25.101 FTP server ready
> USER anonymous
< 331 Anonymous login ok, send your complete email address as your password
> PASS ftp@example.com
< 230-****** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ******
<  ** This is a United States Department of Commerce computer     **
<  ** system, which may be accessed and used only for             **
<  ** official Government business by authorized personnel.       **
<  ** Unauthorized access or use of this computer system may      **
<  ** subject violators to criminal, civil, and/or administrative **
<  ** action.  All information on this computer system may be     **
<  ** intercepted, recorded, read, copied, and disclosed by and   **
<  ** to authorized personnel for official purposes, including    **
<  ** criminal investigations.  Access or use of this computer    **
<  ** system by any person, whether authorized or unauthorized,   **
<  ** constitutes consent to these terms.                         **
<  ****** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ******
< 230 Anonymous access granted, restrictions apply
> PWD
< 257 "/" is the current directory
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD pub
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 CWD command successful
> CWD data
< 250 CWD command successful
> CWD ghcn
< 250 CWD command successful
> CWD daily
< 250 CWD command successful
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||63007|)
*   Trying 205.167.25.101:63007...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connecting to 205.167.25.101 (205.167.25.101) port 63007
* Connected to ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov (205.167.25.101) port 21 (#0)
> TYPE I
< 200 Type set to I
> SIZE ghcnd-stations.txt
< 213 9897052
> RETR ghcnd-stations.txt
< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for ghcnd-stations.txt (9897052 bytes)
* Maxdownload = -1
* Getting file with size: 9897052
* Remembering we are in dir "pub/data/ghcn/daily/"
< 226 Transfer complete
* Connection #0 to host ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov left intact
```

Further, from the AWS instance, I can do standard curl calls to http services.  Here is an example from the AWS box that shows it working:

```
$ curl -L -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" google.com
200
```

I do not have client-side ports 20 and 21 open, and my sysadmin told me that they need to be (and that the business will not open them up).

The other question on superuser that seems relevant is here, and unanswered:

[Unable to connect to FTP server from AWS instance](https://superuser.com/questions/1537718/unable-to-connect-to-ftp-server-from-aws-instance)

How can I make this work, and do I need local ports 20 and/or 21 open for this to work?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=85485

Comment: Judging by that post, it sounds like Nat restrictions are in place by **default**. Make rules in the security settings for 20 ~21

Comment: Outbound or inbound?  Outbound are wide open... Do I need client-side port 20 and 21 accessible?  My understanding was that 20 and 21 are only important on the server side...

Comment: Correct, if you have outbound setup it should work.

Comment: yeah, outbound is wide open, which is why I am still confused as to why it doesn't work.  My sysadmin said that it still depends on client-side port 20 & 21 being open, but that seems just wrong.

Comment: Curl does not get past *outbound* connection attempt to *remote* port 21. Client-side ports do not matter. So either there's something blocking outbound connections on your client machine or local network. Or the remote server blocks connections from your network.